# Why is kapt not working with Kotlin for Node.Js?

Tags: node.js, kotlin, kapt

I wanted to port a kotlin project with gradle building from jvm to node.js. The build.gradle goes as follow:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.js' version '1.3.72'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter();
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-js"
    testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-js"
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.12'
    implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:1.9.2"
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.5'
    kapt 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:1.9.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
kotlin.target.nodejs { }
```

but received the gradle build error

> Could not find method kapt() for arguments [com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:1.9.2]

and while this works fine with kotlin(jvm) project. I wonder why and how to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.